# THREE.Points, parsing JSON, and iterating over materials

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have some lovely JSON exported from Blender using three.js' addon. Works great.

I want to grab colours from each of the materials that the geometry has been exported with and change their material types to "point."

This again works fine according to my console output of the model.material array before and after my .forEach.

Unfortunately, nothing is displayed, as though no material has been applied whatsoever.

As per the inline comment below, a single colour material does work, as do the original materials loaded from the JSON.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var model = loader.parse(json from elsewhere);
var mesh;
var pointMats = [];

model.materials.forEach(function(j) {
  var color = new THREE.Color(j.color.r, j.color.g, j.color.b);
  var specular = new THREE.Color(j.specular.r, j.specular.g, j.specular.b);
  var newPointsMat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    name: j.name,
    color: color,
    lights: true,
    size: 1
  });
  pointMats.push(newPointsMat);
});

// var pointsMat = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { 
//   color: 0xffffff,
//   size: 0.01
// });               // this works fine and is applied to all the meshes in my scene

mesh = new THREE.Points(model.geometry, pointMats);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Of course, no errors are given in the console. Probably because there isn't an error to be displayed.

Thanks for your time

Comment: [THREE.Points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Points) accepts an instance of `Material` as the seconds argument, but you are sending it an array of materials. If you omit the second argument, a PointsMaterial will be created for you. eg. `mesh = new THREE.Points(model.geometry);`. You could try this out quickly to see if that is the problem.

Comment: @2pha pointMats[0] works. does this mean that it accepts only a single instance? and that if wanted multiple sets of point colours that i'd need to split the geometry up?

Comment: That seems to be the easiest option

Comment: THREE.Mesh accepts multiple materials... I'm not sure if THREE.Points does. If you put the same materials onto a mesh, do they appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THREE.Points accepts a single instance of Material and can't handle an array of them on a single mesh.